# How can I find moved question?

Tags: support, questions

I am looking for a question or answer i had provided, but i couldn't find it on superuser.
I guess it was moved somewhere else (i.e. stackoverflow).

How can I search such answers/questions?

Comment: Try `user:me closed:1` in the search box. I'm not sure if it will work for finding answers; but if a question was migrated it will be closed, so this should pick it up (unless it was deleted after the migration...).

Comment: this does not work (seems like user:me gets ignored)

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9785/invoice-software that one?

Comment: you probably have to use your username

Answer (score 2):

If the question has been migrated, then the corresponding answer(s) will be deleted, so there's no way to search that.

You would probably have to search with the question title/keywords, something like `closed:1 <question title/keywords>`